# Как работает конструкция "const reset = () => () =>" и почему в ней две пары скобок?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, typescript

Разбираю код, который был написан до меня, и встретил вот такую конструкцию:

```
export const reset = () => () => {
   axios.post('какой-то URL', { action: 'какой-то action' })
        .then(() => location.reload())
}
```

И я не очень представляю, как работает эта часть: **`const reset = () => () =>`**. Почему и в честь чего здесь 2 пары скобок? Функция вызывается по нажатию. Проект написан на `React` с `TypeScript`.

Comment: Это стрелочные функции, почитайте https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics

Comment: `reset = function(){ return function(){ .... }};` если нагляднее вам будет

Comment: а почему нельзя вернуть axios таким образом: `reset = function(){return axios...}`? Для чего это усложнение?

Comment: reset - в Вашем примере является функцией высшего порядка, которая возвращает функцию.

const example = reset()

Теперь example будет равен функции и Вы можете ее вызвать.
Такие функции часто используют в замыкании.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение) Можете оформить как ответ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const reset` - в Вашем примере является **функцией** высшего порядка, которая **возвращает функцию**.

```
const example = reset()
example()
```

Теперь **example** будет равен **функции** и Вы можете ее вызвать.
Такие **функции** часто используют в **замыкании**.

```
const logNubmer = (number) => () => {
   console.log(number)
}


or 


function logNumber (number) {
     return function () {
          console.log(number)
     }
}

const showNumber = logNumber(3)

showNumber() // console.log(3)
```